# My multi-thread online Server gets too slow when multiple clients connect, C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, server

I'm trying to develop an online game just for fun, with a server and at least 2 clients playing in a single "room". My logic goes as follow, first have the server wait for a client to connect, after the client connects to the server I create a thread for this client (so the client can send messages to the server when it interacts with the main screen). After this if the client wants to play he clicks a button that says "start match" and if another client does the same both goes inside another Thread to play the game only between them. So I create a Thread for each client that connects and a Thread for every 2 clients that want to play.
Now, when i have 2 players playing the game everything goes smooth, the problem is when another 2 players want to play the game the server standalone stops responding (but you can still connect to the server and send messages) and the game gets really slow for the clients.I'm trying to learn about multi-threading that's why i'm doing this project so maybe i'm missing something. I should be creating only 2 threads for each client (when they are actually in game if not only 1) and with 4 clients that's at max 8 Threads, so why is my server getting so slow and crashing?.

**This is where I accept my clients:**

```
private void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;

        ServerClient sc = new ServerClient(listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar));
        sc.SetisInGame(false); // not in game, just in the main menu
        clients.Add(sc);

        new Thread(() => MainPanelRoomThread(sc)).Start();

        StartListening();        
    }
```

**This is my Thread when a client connects:**

```
private void MainPanelRoomThread(ServerClient scThread)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!serverStarted)
                return;

            if (!scThread.GetisInGame()) //check if its not in game so it can receive data
            {
                NetworkStream stream = scThread.tcp.GetStream();

                if (stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, true);
                    string data = streamReader.ReadLine();

                    if (data != null)
                        OnIncomingData(scThread, data); // waiting for that from the client
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**In the OnIncomingData function I wait for a Message saying that the client wants to enter a game so i can start the other thread:**

```
private void OnIncomingData(ServerClient c, string data)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server = " + data);
        string[] aData = data.Split('|');

        switch (aData[0])
        {
            case "CMATCH":
                if (aData[1].Contains("true"))
                {
                    queueClients.Enqueue(c);

                    if (queueClients.Count == 2)
                        new Thread(new ThreadStart(RoomThread)).Start(); //start the Game only if 2 players are waiting for the game to start.
                    else
                        BroadCast("SMATCH|false", c);
                }else if (aData[1].Contains("false"))
                {
                    queueClients.Dequeue();
                    BroadCast("SMATCH|true", c);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Finally the in Game room:**

```
private void RoomThread()
    {
        string msg = "";
        List<ServerClient> players = new List<ServerClient>();
        List<ServerClient> disconnected = new List<ServerClient>();
        int tamanoCola = queueClients.Count;

        for(int i = 0; i < tamanoCola; i++)
        {
            players.Add(queueClients.Dequeue());
            msg = players[i].clientName + "|";
            players[i].isMainPlayer = (i == 0);
            players[i].SetisInGame(true); //its in game 
            BroadCast("SWHO|" + msg + ((players[i].isMainPlayer) ? 1 : 0).ToString(), players[i]);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (!serverStarted)
                return;

            foreach (ServerClient c in players)
            {
                //check if client is still playing (either because the connection died or someone won)
                if (!IsConnected(c.tcp))
                {
                    c.tcp.Close();
                    disconnected.Add(c);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = c.tcp.GetStream();

                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, true);
                        string data = streamReader.ReadLine();

                        if (data != null)
                            OnIncomingData(c, data, players);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (disconnected.Count >= 1)
                return;
        }
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: would using the async stream functions help this a bit?

Comment: You while loops are constantly running with not blocking so as you add more clients you have more code running constantly.

Comment: In addition, creating threads _per client_ doesn't scale.  Look into I/O Completion Ports as used by `async/await`-aware I/O or old school `Beginxxx` operations

Comment: @jdweng I actually need the game room thread running as long as the match is going on, after someone wins i just kill it with a return. But even then with 8 Threads running it shouldnt kill my server.

Comment: @MickyD Oh wow really? didnt know that, i read on another question in Stack  that the way to go was to create a thread for every client. Gonna check out what you told me.

Comment: You do not need a separate thread per client.  The server needs to implement Async Reads which will give the equivalent as separate threads.  You will also need a block so program doesn't terminate.

Comment: @jdweng sorry for the late reply work is driving me crazy. Do you have a tutorial that i could check about that? I been reading some blogs about Async/Await and why i shouldnt i use tasks but im still not sure how to implement it in my server.

Comment: See msdn examples.  They use sockets but can be replaced with any class that inherits the socket like TCPListener and TCPClient : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples